# ImageMagick adding drop shadow to a transparent png being overlaid

Tags: imagemagick, png, transparent, dropshadow

I would like to take this map and overlay it on a basemap I already have prepared.

[transparent png surface weather map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhuTh.png)

How can I add a drop shadow to help make the elements in the png standout?

Here's what I've written to get me everything but the shadow.

convert 91f.png -resize 1789x1080! 91f.png
composite -gravity northwest -geometry 1920x1080+0-20  /tmp/progs/91f.png /var/www/html/output/gfs/sfc/conus-gfs-slp06.png /tmp/progs/prog01.png
composite /home/geoff/basemaps/conus-overlay.png /tmp/progs/prog01.png  /tmp/progs/prog01.png
mv /tmp/progs/prog01.png /var/www/html/output/progs/prog01.png

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please re-read the guide about posting questions and consider whether showing 7 levels of nested directory structure constitutes a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example** Thank you. Also, if you are compositing one image on top of another, your question will need 2 input images...

Comment: What elements need drop shadow? Are you saying to add a drop shadow to the boundary of this image when placing it on another image? If so, post both images. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#shadow

Comment: I have figured it out, but it's a little odd.

`convert  9jh.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 100x1+2+2 \) +swap \
          -background none  -layers merge +repage  9jh.png`